# Quarkus mutiny - missing OAuth2 support for the web-client

Tags: reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny

I have a basic implementation in Quarkus/mutiny (reactive) and are able to consume a REST API using artifact smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web-client. As I use mutiny the Vertx is imported from io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx. I found no compliant Vertx mutiny OAuth2 library.
The artifact vertx-auth-oauth2 (described [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/)) seems to support only bare Vert.x.

Is there OAuth2 support for Vertx mutiny?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we don't have the equivalent (but it's a neat idea, I will add that to the roadmap). However, you can go back to the *bare* vert.x instance by using `vertx.getDelegate()`.

*Update*: Mutiny API will be available in Quarkus 1.9.